# Problems getting camera navigation working in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]I'm trying to work out camera navigation functionality in threejs, using THREE.OrbitControls. Even though I'm following a guide, I just can't seem to get it working.

The link to my fiddle code is: https://jsfiddle.net/Matty1/uc671jbL/18/

It's on line 18/19 of the javascript:

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.update();
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included `OrbitControls` from a relative path in your fiddle. Try it like so:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x19d7f8);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(0,0,5);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width/height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix;
} )

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mugen. Does this work for you? For me, I still have the same problem

Comment: Yes, it works without issues. Do you see any runtime errors in your browser console? Besides, what browser and OS are you using?

Comment: How strange. I am on windows 10 and using google chrome. If i comment out just the line where you add the orbitcontrols, it functions as expected. I've pasted the screenshot above

Comment: Notice that your path to `OrbitControls` is wrong. As I said in my post, you can't use a relative path. So `js/OrbitControls.js` does not work. You also include `three.js` twice. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1oq2ba08/

Comment: Ah... I see :) . Thanks Mugen, I hadn't followed your meaning on that. That's sorted it